# In nested data frame, pass information from one list column to function applied in another

Tags: r, nested, tidyverse, purrr, flextable

I am working on a report for which I have to export a large number of similar data frames into nice looking tables in Word. My goal is to achieve this in one go, using `flextable` to generate the tables and `purrr` / `tidyverse` to apply all the formatting procedures to all rows in a nested data frame. This is what my data frame looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(school = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
            students = c(round(runif(6, 1, 10), 0)),
            grade = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
```

I want to generate separate tables for all groups in column 'school' and started by using the `nest()` function within `tidyr`.

```
list <- df %>% 
        group_by(school) %>%
        nest()
```

This gives me a nested data frame to which I can apply the functions in `flextable` using `purrr`:

```
list <- list %>% 
        mutate(ftables = map(data, flextable)) %>%
        mutate(ftables = purrr::map(ftables, ~ set_header_labels(.,
                                               students = "No of students",
                                               grade = "Grade")))
```

The first `mutate` generates a new column with flextable objects for each school, and the second `mutate` applies header labels to the table, based on the column names that are saved in the object.

My goal is now to add another header that is based on the name of the school. This value resides in the list column entitled `school`, which corresponds row-wise to the tables generated in the list column `ftables`. How can I pass the name of the school to the `add_header` function within `ftables`, using `purrr` or any other procedure?

**Expected output**
I have been able to achieve what I want for individual schools with this procedure (identical header cells will later be merged):

```
school.name <- "A"

ftable.a <- df %>%
            filter(school == "A") %>% 
            select(-school) %>%
            flextable() %>%
            set_header_labels(students = "No of students",
                              grade = "Grade") %>%
            add_header(students = school.name,
                       grade = school.name)

ftable.a
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

package `purrr` provides function map2 that you should use:

```
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)


df <- data.frame(school = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
                 students = c(round(runif(6, 1, 10), 0)),
                 grade = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
byschool <- df %>% 
  group_by(school) %>%
  nest()

byschool <- byschool %>% 
  mutate(ftables = map(data, flextable)) %>%
  mutate(ftables = purrr::map(
    ftables, ~ set_header_labels(.,
                                 students = "No of students",
                                 grade = "Grade"))) %>% 
  mutate(ftables = purrr::map2(ftables, school, function(ft, h){
    add_header(ft, students = h, grade = h)
  } ))
```